# Por que no me funciona mediaquries

Tags: css, web, responsive, mediaqueries

Hola como Están? hace rato estoy intentando poner mis media queries pero no me funcionan. Quiero que hasta los 780px el bloque metodosDePago sea grid y a partir de los 780 sea flex. Ya probé con todos las sugerencias que vi en el foro (como la etiqueta:metaviewport) pero no pude solucionarlo con ninguna. Desde ya muchas gracias y adjunto el código.

```
   <div id="metodosDePago">
    <h2>Metodos de Pago:</h2>
    <div class="parrafo">
      <div class="p1"><p>Efectivo</p></div>
      <div class="p2"><p>Tarjetas de crédito</p></div>
      <div class="p3"><p>Tarjetas de débito</p></div>
      <div class="p4"><p>Transferencia Bancarias</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 780px) {
.navbarr{
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar-toggler-icon {
    filter: invert(1);
}
#metodosDePago{
    .parrafo{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr ;
        grid-row: 1fr 1fr 1fr ;
        grid-row: 2/5;
        .p1{
            grid-column: 1/2;
            grid-row: 2/3;
        }
        .p2{
            grid-column: 2/3;
            grid-row: 2/3;
        }
        .p3{
            grid-column: 1/2;
            grid-row: 3/4;
        }
        .p4{
            grid-column: 2/3;
            grid-row: 3/4;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se está comportando cuando lo intentas? Por favor describe mejor el error :)

Comment: Estás usando algún preprocesador de CSS o algo? No se escriben las reglas de CSS así, no puedes poner estilos de un selector dentro de otro, para eso tienes distintas formas de escribir selectores.